# **VGS** of upper MOSFET disappears after turning on supply voltage

Tags: gate-driving, full-bridge

Why does **VGS** of upper MOSFET in either leg of full bridge drop when the supple voltage across the drain terminals of the upper MOSFETS gets turned on ?[image]

The half bridges separately work perfectly fine but as soon as I connect them together I won't see an output...

Comment: As you know, this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway.

Comment: You mean I put a lot of effort into building the circuit and I want to know why this phenomon happens and you somehow don't like it? If you would be so kind to please remove your comment that would make my weekend better.

Comment: Can you show the circuit diagram?

Comment: How about some more information.  What measurements have you done?  Scope traces? More detailed explanation?

Comment: What does this mean: "voltage across the drain terminals of the upper MOSFETS gets turned on"? Voltages do appear across nodes but surely, in a H bridge, both drains are connected thus there can be only milli volts at best between the drain terminals. Also, did you intend to show a half bridge circuit with the motor grounded? All very confusing!

Comment: Conected to drain of upper mosfets is the main supply voltage (can go up to 500V). Instead of motor I have a resistor connected of 10 kohm

Comment: Why are you showing an irrelevant schematic that only works at 60 volts. Please post the exact schematic and not something that "is somewhat representative". If you previously had 0 volts at the drain then the bootstrap circuit would not work and the gate drive level will be a mess. Also, is the circuit being actively driven with PWM? Plenty to put right and answer.

Comment: You say H bridge, but what H bridge?  All you show is a motor connected to a half bridge at best.  You say you connected half bridges "together".  That's not shown, so we have no idea what you actually did.  Closing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna bet you use a constant DC level at the input for testing.

This turns the top FET on, as it should. However, the top driver, which needs a voltage above the HV rail to drive the top FET gate, is actually powered by capacitor Cboost, which is called a bootstrap cap.

The top driver will eventually consume all the charge in Cboost and thus stop working. CBoost needs to be periodically recharged, which is done by driving the output LOW (ie, top FET off, bottom FET on), which occurs when the PWM is low.

You can't make this kind of driver work on a 100% duty cycle PWM (ie, output constantly on) for this reason. You should only drive it with a PWM value one notch down from 100%. ie, if your PWM counter goes from 0 to 255, don't exceed the value 254.

Note that the 1N4148 used on the schematic will blow on your voltage, but since you didn't post the actual schematic, I'm not worrying about that.

Answer (score 1):

No offense intended but based on the terminology used in your question, I suspect you do not have a good grasp as to how this circuit should function.

The design as shown is called a half-bridge. This means it can only run the motor in one direction. A full-bridge would require 4 MOSFETs and could then perform directional control of the motor

In this circuit, the top FET turns the motor on and off. The bottom FET brings the motor to a rapid stop by a technique known as plug braking (it shorts the motor induced EMF to cause a braking action). The controller will not allow both FETs to be conducting simultaneously as this would essentially short circuit the motor drive voltage to ground.

The motor voltage supply connection is not clearly shown on the sample diagram you clipped from the spec sheet. The motor supply voltage must be applied at the junction of the 1000 uF capacitor and the upper FET.

To test your circuit, hold "In Bottom" low and hold "In Top" high. This should turn on the upper FET and the motor will turn at its maximum speed. Taking "In Top" low should allow the motor to coast to a stop. Pulse width modulating "In Top" would then allow you to control the speed of the motor. To force a rapid braking stop of the motor, take "In Bottom" high and "In Top" low. This will turn off the top FET and then turn on the bottom FET to brake the motor.

Note that this design uses a bootstrap capacitor to control the high side switching of the top FET. Because of this, the controller cannot keep the motor running at top speed at all times since the cap will become depleted and the gate to the high driver will shut off. You must occasionally toggle either control input to refresh the cap.